# Using JavaScript to change the scroll mode of the BROWSER?

Tags: javascript

From JavaScript, how can I change the scroll mode of the browser to put it into the user-controlled autoscroll mode? (Note: I'm **not** asking how to use JavaScript to automatically scroll browser content.)

**Example scenario:** From within a Greasemonkey script, I'm using a 'click' event listener to intercept middle-clicks on links that I want to prevent opening in another tab. This works fine. But I *also* want those middle-clicks to result in the browser going into the user-controlled autoscroll mode, like it does whenever a non-link is middle-clicked.

Is this even possible?